# Is there a way of finding an item in a list that's in a list?

Tags: python, list, append

I'm new to python and i'm experimenting with the functions but i got stuck on this one.
Let's say there are multiple groups in a classroom and a list of names for each group.
I take those lists and i append them to a list that now contains all those lists.
Now is there a function or string of instructions to find a name within a list that's in the list containing all the list of names ? (Even I am confused)

EXAMPLE :

```
TP_A = ['a','b','c']
TP_B = ['d','e','f']
...
TP_F = ['x','y','z']
GROUPS = []
GROUPS.append(TD_A , TD_B , ... , TD_F)
```

Is there a way to ask the computer to find 'y' and for it to return : TP_F ?

Comment: What do you mean with "return TP_F"? You expect a *string* `"TP_F"`, or the list `['x', 'y', 'z']`?

Comment: So, are you actually wanting a program which literally prints: `"TP_F"` as its output, given that you supply `'y'`?

Comment: Note that `GROUPS.append(TD_A , TD_B , ... , TD_F)` is not valid Python.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What, *precisely* are the inputs/outputs you are expecting?

Comment: You should consider using a dictionary with each TP_x as a key instead of populating your namespace with TP_A, TP_B, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the groups such that you are only left with those that contained '*y*'

```
those_with_y = filter(lambda group : 'y' in group, GROUPS)

for group in those_with_y:
    print(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create a function and use kwargs:

```
>>> TP_A = ['a','b','c']
>>> TP_B = ['d','e','f']
>>> TP_F = ['x','y','z']
>>> def find_y(**kwargs):
...   for name, lst in kwargs.items():
...     if 'y' in lst:
...       return name
...
>>> find_y(TP_A=TP_A, TP_B=TP_B, TP_F=TP_F)
'TP_F'
```

the same function would work on GROUPS if you change it from a list to a dictionary:

```
>>> GROUPS={'TP_A':TP_A, 'TP_B':TP_B, 'TP_F':TP_F}
>>> find_y(**GROUPS)
'TP_F'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `globals()` with list comprehension:

```
TP_A = ['a','b','c']
TP_B = ['d','e','f']
TP_F = ['x','y','z']
GROUPS = [TP_A, TP_B, TP_F]

def check_group(name):
     return [n for g in GROUPS for n in globals() if name in g if id(globals()[n]) == id(g)]

print(*check_group('y'))

# TP_F
```

Or `yield` with loop:

```
TP_A = ['a','b','y']
TP_B = ['d','e','f']
TP_F = ['x','y','z']
GROUPS = [TP_A, TP_B, TP_F]

def check_group(name):
    for group in GROUPS:
        for var in globals():
            if name in group and id(globals()[var]) == id(group):
                yield var

print(*check_group('y'))

# TP_A TP_F
```